# How do I retain hover state on parent navigation element while moving your mouse to the sub menu?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to add a bit of spacing between my main menu element and sub menu element.

```
   .dropdown-menu{
        margin-top:10px;
    }
```

After adding that the sub-menu is placed where I want it but hovering over "Harry Potter Books" and then trying to mouse from that to the sub-menu, the sub-menu disappears.

I want to be able to hover over the main menu item and be able to mouse over to the sub menu.

Please see this codepen, I am using Bootstrap to implement the base menu styles.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErVEZj?editors=11000#0

Let me know if there are any other pieces of information I can provide.

Comment: You could try replacing the `margin-top` with something like `border-top: 10px solid transparent;` ... but seems kinda hacky. Should probably try and make the `<a>` take up the full height of the nav bar. Seems like a better fix.

Comment: Nice, thats a decent work around. I'll put that in place for now and keep looking for a better way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Use padding-top instead of the margin-top. You might need to restructure your divs but I would think that is the less hacky way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the `.navbar-nav>li>a` (the thing you are hovering) take up the full height of the navbar since you want the dropdown menu below the navbar.

To easily do this with your code simply move the 10px of margin top and bottom from the `.navbar-nav` to padding top and bottom of the `.navbar-nav>li>a`. Then you can remove that `margin-top: 10px` from the dropdown menu that creates that anti-hovering gap.

```css
/*Navbar styles*/

.nav-element {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin-left: 20px !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-right: 20px !important;
  padding-left: 20px !important;
  padding-top: 15px !important;
  padding-bottom: 15px !important;
  color: white !important;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#nav:hover>#nav-details {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}


/*Divider style for sub-menu */

.divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.dropdown-menu {}

.navbar-nav>li {
  margin-top: 5px;
}


/*these css blocks contain style for the arrow on the sub-menu*/

.dropdown-menu:after,
.dropdown-menu:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 80px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
  border-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu:before {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #;
  border-width: 13px;
  margin-left: -13px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/*styles for list elements and hover logic */

li {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li span a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover>a:after {
  background: orangered;
}

ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover>ul,
ul li>ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover>ul,

/*maintain hover state of parent list in sub menus*/

ul li:focus-within>ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" style="background-color:royalblue;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse" style="background-color:royalblue;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="nav" class="nav-element" aria-haspopup="true">
          <a>Harry Potter Books</a>
          <ul id="nav-details" aria-label="submenu" class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sorcerer's Stone</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chamber of Secrets</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Deathly Hallows</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Goblet of Fire</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-element" id="ltc-program-nav">
          <a>Books Better than Harry Potter</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-element" id="ApplyNowTopLevel">
          <a>Another Funny Link</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Too fast for me, zgood! I created a fork of the codepen though, if that's easier. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzpdRY?editors=1100